# C++ : Inserting Operator + and - In an array and check if it is possible to create n

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Problem : If you were given a number n, you will have an array with (n-1) index. with the 1st index containing 1, 2nd index containing 2, and n-1 index containing n-1. Given those sets of numbers, How can one check when + or -, the array can be equal to n? 
Example :

```
n = 3, Array = {1,2}  
+1 +2 = 3 (True)  
n = 4, Array = {1,2,3}  
-1 + 2 + 3 = 4 (True)  
n = 5, Array = {1,2,3,4}
```

No possible combination
I tried too long to think about it and still haven't come up with the right answer :(

Comment: Small tip to help you start: you can use booleans to represent + and - (eg. + = 1, - = 0)

Comment: 5 cannot be done.  If you add all the number you get 10.  Any numbers that are subtracted will reduce that by twice their value and hence will yield an even total.  There is thus no way to obtain an odd value such as five.  I think the same proof holds (in reverse) for six.  7 = 1 + 2 - 3 -4 + 5 + 6.

Comment: Holy... Now i get the idea! Thank you very much! (Q.Q Only now i have realized it. Thank you)

Answer (score 1):

If you ale looking for simple **solvable/not solvable** answer, then it seems the answer if very simple

```
 (sum - n) % 2 != 0 // => non-solvable
```

Here is result of an experiment:

[image]

When n gets larger it becomes easier to subtract necessary sum and there are plenty of possible solutions.